# pip install ez-setup is giving python setup.py egg_info error

Tags: python, pip

I'm running into the following error when trying to run pip install `ez_setup`:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
/private/var/folders/wb/z3f0rbyx7pj5zz_3pj5dkq5h0000gp/T/pip-build-HZDM61/ez-setup/
```

Whenever I run `pip install -U pip setuptools`, it says that everything is up to date

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Report here: https://github.com/ActiveState/ez_setup (What are you doing in SO?)

Comment: Having the same issue.